# when tray to build flutter APK

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout, fluent-nhibernate

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Script 'C:\Users\LEGION\flutter_windows_2.2.3-stable\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1005
- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildRelease'.

> Process 'command 'C:\Users\LEGION\flutter_windows_2.2.3-stable\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I just solved this problem, maybe it can help

**solution**

**Step 1** delete your flutter folder and build it again in new folder

**Step 2** compile again